# Meaning of '&variable' in arguments/patterns

Tags: pointers, syntax, rust

What does `&variable` mean when it is used in patterns or closure arguments?

```
for &code in self.exit_code.iter() { ... }

let mut new_seps = do seps.iter().fold(~[]) |result, &next| { ... }
```

Here we have `&code` and `&next` in `for` loop and closure definition. What do `&` sign in these mean? Why cannot we simply use `code` and `next`, without the ampersand? Is it related to `ref` qualifier in pattern matching? Is it related to `&` in `self` argument in trait implementations?

I couldn't find anything on this syntax neither in [current Rust reference manual](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.8/rust.html#do-expressions) nor in [tutorial](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.8/tutorial.html). Currently I think this is some kind of implicit dereferencing (this follows from error message which appears if I omit `&` in the pattern), but I'm not sure.

Comment: I'd say it means "capture by borrowing pointer" rather than "by value".

Comment: @KerrekSB, so does that mean that if in `|result, next|` `next` has type `T`, then in `|result, &next|` `next` has `&T` type?

Comment: I would have thought so, but I'm not sure, either. As you say, the manual is a bit lacking in that regard... this should be easy enough to try, though!

Comment: Well, removing or adding `&` in my code leads to rather cryptic message. My example may be a bit complex though...

Comment: If you have a pointer type, I think you must dereference with `*` (though there are cases of auto-dereferencing, like array subscripts); so if you try to omit the `*` and it really is passed by borrowing pointer, you should see an error to that effect. (I can try it myself later when I'm at a machine with a rust compiler.)

Comment: @KerrekSB, I'm using `next` in a comparison: `if next == "\\s" { ... }`, and omitting `&` gives `error: mismatched types: expected `&&str` but found `&'static str` (expected &-ptr but found &'static str)`. If `&` is present then all is OK. It seems that there is a problem when using static lifetimes... I'll check it later.

Comment: What about `if *next == "\\s"`?

Comment: @KerrekSB, yes, explicit dereference works, exactly as follows from dbaupp's answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a pattern match, "destructuring" something of type `&T`. That is, in

```
let &x = &1i;
```

`x` has type `int`, and value 1. So it's actually the opposite to `ref` (which does what @KerrekSB is saying, `ref x` captures by reference rather than by value).

One can regard it as similar to

```
match returns_an_option() {
    Some(a) => { ... }
    None => { ... }
}
```

except the constructor of `&T` is `&`, not `Some` or `None`.

---

In this specific instance, I guess `seps` is a vector (the error you state indicates it's probably a `&[&str]`), so the `.iter()` returns an object that implements `Iterator<& &str>`, that is, it is an iterator over references to the elements of the vector (`&str`), thus, you need to dereference `next` somehow to get to the original `&str`. This can be done by `&` in a pattern match (as the code demonstrates) *or* with `*next` when it is used.

(Note that the `&` patterns only work with implicitly copyable types, as one cannot move ownership out from a reference/*borrowed* pointer (i.e. `&T`).)

Comment: Yeah, you're entirely correct. It is `&[&str]` vector. I didn't catch that `iter()` returns `Iterator<&T>` instead of `Iterator<T>`, hence the confusion. So, it really is some kind of implicit dereference, and it also goes nicely with pattern match semantics, as I suspected. Thank you very much.