# Why does this HashMap key have to be dereferenced twice?

Tags: rust

This function computes the mode of a `Vec<i32>` using a `HashMap` to keep count of the occurrence of each value. I do not understand why this will not compile unless the key is deferenced twice in this last line:

```
fn mode(vec: &Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
    let mut counts = HashMap::new();

    for n in vec {
        let count = counts.entry(n).or_insert(0);
        *count += 1;
    }

    **counts.iter().max_by_key(|a| a.1).unwrap().0
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be dereferenced twice because you've created a double reference.

1. You are [iterating over `&Vec<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-IntoIterator) which [produces `&T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html#impl-Iterator).
2. You called [`HashMap::iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.iter) on `HashMap<K, V>` which [produces `(&K, &V)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.Iter.html#impl-Iterator).

```
fn mode(vec: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    let mut counts = std::collections::HashMap::new();

    for &n in vec {
        *counts.entry(n).or_insert(0) += 1;
    }

    counts.into_iter().max_by_key(|a| a.1).unwrap().0
}
```

See also:

- [What is the difference between iter and into_iter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34733811/155423)
- [What does it mean to pass in a vector into a `for` loop versus a reference to a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036279/155423)
- [Iterating over a slice's values instead of references in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40613725/155423)
- [Meaning of '&variable' in arguments/patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19066402/155423)
- [What is the difference between `e1` and `&e2` when used as the for-loop variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45197826/155423)
- [What is the purpose of `&` before the loop variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57339201/155423)
- [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)