# What does this Rust Closure argument syntax mean?

Tags: rust, closures, destructuring

I modified code found on the internet to create a function that obtains the statistical mode of any Hashable type that implements Eq, but I do not understand some of the syntax. Here is the function:

```rust
use std::hash::Hash;
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub fn mode<'a, I, T>(items: I) -> &'a T 
where I: IntoIterator<Item = &'a T>, 
      T: Hash + Clone + Eq, {
  let mut occurrences: HashMap<&T, usize> = HashMap::new();

  for value in items.into_iter() {
      *occurrences.entry(value).or_insert(0) += 1;
  }

  occurrences
      .into_iter()
      .max_by_key(|&(_, count)| count)
      .map(|(val, _)| val)
      .expect("Cannot compute the mode of zero items")
}
```

(I think requiring `Clone` may be overkill.)

The syntax I do not understand is in the closure passed to map_by_key:

`|&(_, count)| count`

What is the `&(_, count)` doing? I gather the underscore means I can ignore that parameter. Is this some sort of destructuring of a tuple in a parameter list? Does this make `count` take the reference of the tuple's second item?

Comment: It's pattern matching used for destructuring, yes. When your type is `&(_, count)`, `.max_by_key(|&(_, count)| count)` is equivalent to `.max_by_key(|v| v.1)`. It lets you have a cleaner name inside the closure rather than using the `.1` access.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066402/meaning-of-variable-in-arguments-patterns

Comment: Yes, that related question is helpful, especially about the restriction to Copyable types of & destructuring.

Comment: may_by_key is a function that accepts a closure with one parameter which is a reference to a tuple with two elements. The closure does nothing but returns back only the second element from the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

`.max_by_key(|&(_, count)| count)` is equivalent to `.max_by_key(f)` where f is this:

```
fn f<T>(t: &(T, usize)) -> usize {
    (*t).1
}
```

`f()` could also be written using pattern matching, like this:

```
fn f2<T>(&(_, count): &(T, usize)) -> usize {
    count
}
```

And `f2()` is much closer to the first closure you're asking about.

The second closure is essentially the same, except there is no reference slightly complicating matters.